# Meteor.publish with call to an async function returning error

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor, async-await

I am trying to create a wrapper method for Meteor.publish that does an access check before actually calling it.

The access check is represented by an async-await method, which leads to the following error in my wrapper function when running it, if I convert my wrapper method to an async one.

> Exception from sub alerts.notAcknowledged id 2 Error: Publish function
> can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors    at
> Subscription._publishHandlerResult
> (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1132:18)

If I remove the async keyword from the wrapper method and comment out the call to the async-await method, the wrapper method is working as expected.

Comment: If your solution worked, you can answer your own question, rather than putting the solution in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any answer to solve my issue, but after checking several solutions and trying out, I got to the following solution:

```
export const wrapperPublish = (metadata: any, callback: Function) => {
     Meteor.publish(metadata.name, (params: LooseObject) => {

        const allowAccessSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(allowAccess);
        const { error, hasAccess } = MeteorPromise.await(allowAccessSync({
                                     token: params.token,
                                     methodName: params.methodName,
                                     }, () => {}));
        check(params, metadata.checks);
        if (!hasAccess) {
            // do something 
        }

        return callback(params);
    });
};
```

In the code snippet above, the allowAccess represents the function returning a Promise and the solution was the Meteor.wrapAsync that transforms an async function into a convenient synchronous-looking function.
https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync

Comment: Yes, wrapAsync is a current solution. In Meteor 2.3 there is going to be a better support for async publishes, see here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/11444